# Error creating bean By @Resource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am tiring to to build a small application with spring+hibernate+maven+postgreSQL but when i am tiring to inject dependency in my controller and service class it creates problem for injecting the dependency here is the code and logs please give your suggestion to solve this wiring problem?

```
mvc-dispature-servlet.xml

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


 <context:component-scan base-package="com.bms" /> 
 <context:annotation-config />



<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bms" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="*******" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.bms.Domain.Book</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```
Controller class BooksEntryController.java

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard/*")
 public class BooksEntryController {

@Resource
private BookFormService bookFormServiceImp;

@RequestMapping(value = "/booksentryform", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewBooksEntryForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("test", new Book());
    return new ModelAndView("bookregistrationform");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addbookdetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBook(@ModelAttribute("test") Book book, Model model) {

    if (book != null) {
        bookFormServiceImp.addBooks(book);
        return "bookaddsuccessfully";

    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

}
 }


Service interface BookFormService.java

   public interface BookFormService {
void addBooks(Book book);
      }

ServiceImp class BookFormServiceImp.java

   @Service("bookFormServiceImp")

   public class BookFormServiceImp implements BookFormService {

@Resource
private BookFormDao bookFormDaoImp ;

public void addBooks(Book book) {
    bookFormDaoImp.addBook(book);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

  }


  Dao interface BookFormDao .java 

    public interface BookFormDao {
public void addBook(Book book); }

DaoImp class BookFormDaoImp.java

   @Repository("bookFormDaoImp")
    public class BookFormDaoImp implements BookFormDao {
@Resource
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public void addBook(Book book) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getCurrentSession().save(book);

}

    }
```

Here is the log :

```
2013-06-20 00:35:51.528:INFO:/bms:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 20, 2013 12:35:51 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jun 20, 2013 12:35:51 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jun 20 00:35:51 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 20, 2013 12:35:51 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Jun 20, 2013 12:35:52 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2df8f8: defining beans [booksEntryController,bookFormDaoImp,bookFormServiceImp,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 20, 2013 12:35:52 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2df8f8: defining beans [booksEntryController,bookFormDaoImp,bookFormServiceImp,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 20, 2013 12:35:52 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'booksEntryController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookFormServiceImp': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookFormDaoImp': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
        ...................................
        ....................................
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing some jars.

Comment: Which versions of hibernate and spring are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the right `sessionFactory` class. If you are using `Hibernate 4`, use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`.

Replace

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
```

by

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```